# Same space between the first and second word in different lines

Tags: spacing, layout

I’d like to create an environment like in the picture. I’ve considered setting the spaces with an itemize environment but is there an easier trick to set the tabs?
[image]

Comment: You can use a simple `tabular` environment.

Comment: Alternativley you can place the first word into a box with a given width, using `\makebox[<width>][l]{...}` or `\hbox to <width>{...\hfill}`.

Answer (score 1):

This version provides a fixed gap between the two fields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Centerstack[l]{Name:\\Address:\\Country:}%
\hspace{25pt}%
\Centerstack[l]{Max Mustermann\\Musterstrasse\\Germany}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the right hand column being at a fixed location, try this...the `\tabto` acts as a tab.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\Centerstack[l]{Name:\\Address:\\Country:}%
\tabto*{1in}%
\Centerstack[l]{Max Mustermann\\Musterstrasse\\Germany}
\end{document}
```